# Tapestry 5.4, Ajax Form Validation doesn't show field errors

Tags: ajax, validation, tapestry

I'm using Tapestry 5.4.1 but also tried it with 5.4. I only want an Ajax-enabled form with field validation. Basically, I want exactly this:
http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart7/examples/ajax/form

However, I was not able to get the field-based error report to show when Ajax is enabled (without Ajax it works fine). That means, I want the default behaviour where the input field would get a red border and an error message printed below it in case the entered value is not valid. But I couldn't get it to work.

So I just completely copied the example. But also the example doesn't work so now I'm really out of ideas. On the Jumpstart page the example is working, however it is obviously not using the shown code because the examples gives an error on an empty first name but the example gives an error when the first name is "Acme". I can see in my logs that the form validation is done and that the error is recognized and I can also switch on the error message using the globalOnly option on the errors element set to false.

But I can't get the input field to get styled an show its error.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Edit: Here all the resources I am using:

Java class:

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Past;

import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Import;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.InjectComponent;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form;
import org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.TextField;
import org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Zone;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject;
import org.apache.tapestry5.services.Request;
import org.apache.tapestry5.services.ajax.AjaxResponseRenderer;

@Import(stylesheet = "js.css")
public class FormTest {
    // Screen fields

    @Property
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @Property
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @Property
    @NotNull
    @Past
    private Date birthday;

    // Generally useful bits and pieces

    @Inject
    private Request request;

    @InjectComponent("ajaxForm")
    private Form form;

    @InjectComponent("firstName")
    private TextField firstNameField;

    @InjectComponent
    private Zone formZone;

    @Inject
    private AjaxResponseRenderer ajaxResponseRenderer;

    // The code

    void setupRender() {
        if (firstName == null && lastName == null && birthday == null) {
            firstName = "Humpty";
            lastName = "Dumpty";
            birthday = new Date(0);
        }
    }

    void onValidateFromAjaxForm() {

        // Note, this method is triggered even if server-side validation has already found error(s).

        System.out.println(firstName);
        if (firstName != null && firstName.equals("Acme")) {
            System.out.println("Fehler");
            form.recordError(firstNameField, "First Name must not be Acme.");
        }

    }

    void onSuccess() {
        if (request.isXHR()) {
            System.out.println("Success");
            ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(formZone);
        }
    }

    void onFailure() {
        if (request.isXHR()) {
            System.out.println("Failure");
            ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(formZone);
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public Date getServerTime() {
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- We need a doctype to allow us to use special characters like &nbsp; 
     We use a "strict" DTD to make IE follow the alignment rules. -->

<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_4.xsd">
<body class="container">
    <h3>AJAX Form</h3>

    <noscript class="js-required">
        ${message:javascript_required}
    </noscript>     

    <p>This page demonstrates how Tapestry AJAX-enables a Form if you specify the zone parameter of the Form.</p>

    <div class="eg">
        <t:zone t:id="formZone" id="formZone">
            <t:form t:id="ajaxForm" class="form-horizontal" async="true">

                <t:errors globalOnly="false"/>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <t:label for="firstName" class="col-sm-2"/>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <t:textfield t:id="firstName"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <t:label for="lastName" class="col-sm-2"/>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <t:textfield t:id="lastName"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <t:label for="birthday" class="col-sm-2"/>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <t:datefield t:id="birthday"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                        <t:submit value="Accept"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                Welcome ${name}. Your birthday is ${birthday}
            </t:form>
        </t:zone>
    </div>  

    Note that the following time field does not update because it's not in the zone:  ${serverTime}<br/><br/>

    References: 
    <a href="http://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Form.html">Form</a>, 
    <a href="http://tapestry.apache.org/ajax-and-zones.html">Ajax and Zones</a>, 
    <a href="http://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Zone.html">Zone</a>, 
    <a href="http://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/ajax/AjaxResponseRenderer.html">AjaxResponseRenderer</a>, 
    <a href="http://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/Request.html">Request</a>, 
    <a href="http://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ioc/annotations/Inject.html">@Inject</a>, 
    <a href="http://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/annotations/InjectComponent.html">@InjectComponent</a>, 
    <a href="http://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/coffeescript/zone.html">t5/core/zone</a>, 
    <a href="http://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/coffeescript/ajax.html">t5/core/ajax</a>, 
    <a href="http://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/coffeescript/forms.html">t5/core/forms</a>.<br/><br/> 

    <t:pagelink page="Index">Home</t:pagelink><br/><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

js.css:

```
.eg {
                margin: 20px 0;
                padding: 14px;
                color: #888;
                border: 1px solid #ddd;
                border-radius: 6px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
                -mox-border-radius: 6px;
}

.js-required {
                color: red;
                display: block;
                margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.js-recommended {
                color: red;
                display: block;
                margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

Comment: How do you try to validate? What are the conditions?
I know its not the solution, but if you check basic stuff, you can use [validate in tml](http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html)

Comment: Actually, I just want to check if there the field value is empty or not. On an empty field, an error message should be shown. You're right, I could just do it myself, but what do I have Tapestry for, then? Also I don't know how I would integrate by own JavaScript logic into the JavaScript workings of Tapestry.

Comment: 1. Its weird.. Because it is working in my project what I am currently working on.. ( you can use `validate="required"` in the textfield tag btw) But I totally understand your thoughts.. Maybe you should edit the question, and copy your java and tml file, It can be a semantical problem..
2. I suggest you to ask your js problem in a different question, and I will take a look at it, maybe I can help ;)

Comment: I added the class and the template. It's really just the Jumpstart stuff minus some tab component that doesn't come by default with Tapestry at that shouldn't have anything to do with the issue at hand. Thank you!

Comment: Try to hardcode field ids via t:clientId="...". It seems that tapestry each time generates unique ids for fields and can't locate errors in tracker for new ids then.

Comment: That's it, xl0e, thank you! I know that Tapestry generates unique IDs for fields in Ajax response markup (see http://tapestry.apache.org/ajax-components-faq.html towards the end). I didn't know the t:clientId parameter, thank you so much. That also makes my JavaScript code simpler because currently, I always pass the actual client IDs. You would think, Tapestry would take of these issues introduced by itself, wouldn't you?! If you add this as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a difference between the [jumpstart](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart7/examples/ajax/form) description and the real form. I don't know if it causes the problem but if you check the source of the jumpstart example (inspect element in firefox) 
the form tag has some extra variables:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" data-async-trigger="true" data-validate="submit" action="/jumpstart7/examples/ajax/form.ajaxform" method="post" id="ajaxForm">
```

Maybe if you add the `data-async-trigger="true"` variable it will work.

Comment: This didn't change anything for me. xl0e got the catch: I have to use t:clientId="..." on the input element

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to Tapestry cilent Validation? Tapestry5.4 clientValidation you must set your AppModule contributeApplicationDefaults method like this:

```
configuration.add(SymbolConstants.FORM_CLIENT_LOGIC_ENABLED, true);
```

Remove the zone, if FORM_CLIENT_LOGIC_ENABLED = true, when you click your submit btn,you can see the form errors and the project url like this:http://localhost:8080/projectanme/FormTest. It mean is realy clientValidation.
If FORM_CLIENT_LOGIC_ENABLED = false,when you click your submit btn,you can see the form errors and the project url like this:http://localhost:8080/projectanme/FormTest.ajaxform It mean is not clientValidation.

More tapestry5.4 tutorials,you can see tapestry5-cms and tapestry-widgets code in github

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it is not necessary. Please see the comment of xl0e to the original question. The issue is solved by giving each zone an individual id but the same t:id (since component IDs cannot be dynamic).